# Oracle view result - Strange order of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing a strange problem while doing a reporting with oracle.

For example.

When I execute

```
Select col1,col2,col3 
  from table
```

I am getting the expected order of columns in the result - `col1, col2, col3`.

But, when I create a view and select, for example:

```
create view report_view as 
  Select col1,col2,col3 
    from table
```

and then do

```
select * 
  from report_view
```

the order of columns in the result is - `col1, col3, col2`.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? 
For your information, previously I had only `col1` and `col3` in my view and I added `col2`  recently in my view.

Comment: There is [no way to add a column to an Oracle view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4004.htm).

Comment: What does `desc table` and `desc report_view` display?

Comment: Show the code by which you added the new column to the view, please.

Comment: You can also look at `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'REPORT_VIEW', user) from dual`, or look at `user_views.text` to see how the view was created (you might need to `set long 30000` first to see it all); if that differs from what you think (and it appears to) then you seem to have a deployment process issue, not an Oracle issue.

Answer (score 1):

Issue the query below and check `COLUMN_ID` to know in which order your columns will be shown when you use `*` in your `select` statement.

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_ID 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = '[YOUR_VIEW_NAME_HERE]'
```

If you insist on using `*` in your view, then you must drop/create your table and order the 
columns in the way you need them to be.

Comment: i ordered the columns in the way i need. still, it's showing the wrong order in result

Answer (score 0):

You probably added col2 as the last column in your view. The order is like it is in your create statement